# GUID field from data base table in external list

Tags: external-list, guid

I created an external list based on table from data base.

But one field in my table has type "uniqueidentifier" for GUID values and does not display in external list.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUIDs are not supported by External List, however you can use Business Data Web Part which connects to External Content type and can display GUIDs..

Look at the link below, specifically the part half way down entitled **"Deploy the solution and create new page to see the associated data lists"**. It is very useful to link up data between tables too using Business Data Related Lists.

[Walkthrough of creating association between Sharepoint BDC entities using Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/08/02/walkthrough-of-creating-association-between-sharepoint-bdc-entities-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Source:

[How to import GUID columns from SQL database via External Content Type in SharePoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478480/how-to-import-guid-columns-from-sql-database-via-external-content-type-in-sharep)

Also have a look at:

[How To: So you have a GUID in your External List](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2010/04/17/how-to-so-you-have-a-guid-in-your-external-list-huh-yes-you-can-update-the-list-if-you-set-it-up-right/)